# Evaluting $\tan15°$ using difference formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Evalute $\tan15°$ using difference formula

Steps I took:

$$\begin{align}
\tan(45-30)&=\frac { \tan(45)-\tan(30) }{ 1+\tan(45)\tan(30) }\\
&=\frac { 1-\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 }  }{ 1+\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 }  } \\
&=\frac { 1-\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 }  }{ 1+\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 }  } \cdot \frac { 1-\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 }  }{ 1-\frac { \sqrt3 }{ 3 }  }\\
&=\frac { 1-\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 } -\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 } +\frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }{ 1-\frac { 1 }{ 3 }  } \\
\end{align}$$

Where do I go from here to arrive at the correct answer? And what mistakes did I make, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Hint: Go on**

$$\frac { 1-\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 } -\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 } +\frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }{ 1-\frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }=\frac { 1-\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 } -\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 3 } +\frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }{ 1-\frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }\cdot\frac33=
\frac {3-2\sqrt3+1 }{3-1}=
\frac {4-2\sqrt3}{2}=2-\sqrt3$$

> [$$\large\tan15^{\circ}=2-\sqrt3$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan+15+degrees)

Comment: You multiplied it by $3$?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer To both numerator and denominator!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-\dfrac1{\sqrt3}}{1+\dfrac1{\sqrt3}}=\frac{\dfrac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3}}{\dfrac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt3}}$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+1}=\frac{(\sqrt3-1)^2}{(\sqrt3+1)(\sqrt3-1)}=?$$